Murim manhwa in which the main character's friend is killed and turned into a puppet by their master
I'm trying to find a manhwa where the main character (MC) and his friend meet their master. The master, however, went out one day with his friend, killed the friend and turned him into a puppet of sorts. The MC hides his powers and tricks his old master into believing he's still weak, then kills him. I faintly remember him also using poison too.
That's really all I remember. If anyone could help that would be awesome.

It is called: Legend of an Asura - The Poison Dragon.
From Anime Planet:

The mighty Medicine Faction has fallen to the evil hands of the Venom Clan. As they travel across the land, taking out each clan under the faction, Zhen Ziqiang becomes a test subject for the Elder of the Venom Clan. After being injected with various poisons, Ziqiang rises from the depths of hell as an Asura. Full of anger, he escapes and begins to plan his revenge as the sole survivor of his faction. Now, his goal is to destroy the entire Poison Faction and give them a taste of their own venom.


Can you explain why this is a match?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You can improve your answer if you [edit] it to add details about the work, like a synopsis or an explanation of how it matches the question.
